# Why is my "extrude mesh" offset scale uneven (Geometry nodes)

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to make levels for my game in a more procedural way and thought that geometry nodes would be the perfect way to start doing that, I'm trying to create some walls and an edge around this walls (2.5D game)

I have this so far but the second "extrude mesh" node is extruding the edges very unevenly, I suppose it may have something to do with the normals of the vertices not being correct but I'm not sure, how would I go solving this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]